# mapping of row in one table to column in another table?

Tags: sql

i have a data set where in i take value from one table which itself is a column in another table. it would look something like this.

```
TABLE1

ID    CATEGORY   ACTIVITY
551    ML         ART
552    PTL        SWEEPS
553    RDC        PIPO
554    ML         PIPO

TABLE2

ACTIVITY       ML   PTL  RDC 
ART            10   15   15 
PIPO           15   15   11
SWEEPS         12   10   15
```

NOW SUPPOSE I WANT FOR 551 ID AND CATEGORY 'ML' IN TABLE1 TO FETCH VALUE OF ML i.e '10' IN TABLE2 FOR ACTIVITY 'ART'. 
how do i do this in sql?

Answer (score 1):

Either using a subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  activity = (SELECT activity 
                   FROM   table1 
                   WHERE  id = 551)
```

OR using a join

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM   table2 t2 
       JOIN table1 t1 
         ON t2.activity = t1.activity 
            AND t1.id = 551
```